# Netbeans 11 Cannot Add JDK 7

Tags: windows-7, java, netbeans

I have installed Apache Netbeans 11.1 and JDK 12 to try it out. After installation I tried installing some plugins (some are failing to activate for some reason) and then tried adding my JDK platforms.

I added JDK 8 without problem, but when I tried installing JDK 7 I get the following error:

`Cannot detect and install the selected platform. The java or javac may not be executable.`

I know that my JDK 7 installation is fine because I can still run my Netbeans 8.2 projects that use this platform without a problem. I also tried with JDK 6 but I get the same problem.

Has Apache Netbeans ended support for JDKs that are lower than 8 or could it be something else?

Here are some more details:

- OS: Windows 7 x64
- NetBeans: Apache Netbeans 11.1
- netbeans_jdkhome: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2"
- JDKs Directory: C:\Program Files\Java\

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Example JDK 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsX9v.png)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Netbeans that indicates you are pointing to the location of the JDK 7.  "Has Apache Netbeans ended support for JDKs that are lower than 8 or could it be something else?" - Nope

Comment: @Ramhound Please see edits for screenshots.

Comment: Why are you selecting a *.zip file instead of the JDK 7 bin directory?  I have always pointed NetBeans to Java within NetBeans itself (part of the solution).  Remember you likely downloaded JRE 8 and have JDK 7.  *Show the screen that indicates you are pointing to JDK 8.*

Comment: @Ramhound I am selecting the JDK 7 directory and the zip file is selected automatically after clicking "Next". I have added a screenshot of how JDK 8 is handled, showing that the zip file is also selected.

Comment: I've also encountered the exact behavior, maybe it's a bug ?

Comment: @svarog I just found out this IS a bug that has been detected back in July and it seems they will change this on 11.2 (see: [BUG](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2878) and [GITHUB](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1396) )

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer for other readers ?!

Comment: @svarog Posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

After further reasearch I found that this error is a known bug detected a while back.

Here is the link to the [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2878) as well as the [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/pull/1396) associated. It seems that they will fix this on Netbeans 11.2, so now it's just a matter of waiting for their next release.